# Is a Flex debugger included in the sdk?

Tags: apache-flex

I have been writing Flex applications for a few months now and luckily have not needed a full debugger as of yet, so far I have just used a few Alert boxes...

Is there an available debugger that is included in the free Flex SDK? I am not using FlexBuilder (I have been using Emacs and compiling with ant).

If not, how do you debug Flex applications without FlexBuilder? (note: I have no intentions of using flexbuilder)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A debugger called `fdb` is included in the Flex SDK. Here's some documentation on how to use it:

- [Adobe DevCenter: Debugging Client-Side Code in Flex Applications](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/client_debug_08.html)
- [Flex 3 Help: Using the Command-Line Debugger](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=debugging_01.html)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when programming with ActionScript and having to test it on a browser. Try [this](http://www.flex888.com/649/debugging-flex-with-thunderbolt.html). It involves using Firefox (which I believe you do) and FireBug to receive the debug messages.

Comment: A debugger is much more than something that shows debug messages. It lets you break the running application and step through the code line by line watching the values of variables change as each statement executes.